# Touchscreen Support for Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: 12.04, lenovo, touchscreen

Im currently using a Lenovo IdeaPad P400 Touch and created a LiveUSB version of Ubuntu 12.04LTS and I'm wondering how to get the touchscreen working on ubuntu. I have read a couple of forums and saw answers for Ubuntu 13 and I'm also aware it has an issue with the time it takes to recognize the touchscreen device. I am a relatively novice linux user, but have been using it for quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a similar question recently. Am I the only one who finds it ironic that Canonical claims Ubuntu is touch optimised, yet touchscreens still do not work "out of the box" in Ubuntu 12.04 or 13.10?

Now a "sort of" fix. I have the same model & while touch screen does not work perfectly, you can make it work "relatively well" by putting your computer into suspend, wait 30 seconds, then wake it. My touch screen functions (although not with all of the capability it does in Windows) pretty well.